# Regular Expressions in R (Multiple combinations of a string)

Tags: r

Please, I would like to ask a question about regular expressions in R. Below is the code:

```
string <- "BROCA DIN 338 4,00 MM"

string_list <- regmatches(x=string, gregexpr("[0-9]+\\s\\w+", text=string))

words <- sapply(string_list, toString)
words[is.na(string_list)] <- NA

words <- gsub(pattern = "[[:punct:]]+", replacement="", x=words)

regmatches(x=words, gregexpr("[0-9]+[[:space:]]+\\w+", text=words))
```

After this, the result is as follows:

> ```
> [1] "338 4" "00 MM"
> ```

My problem is that I have to use grepl in the following way:

```
dose_1KG <- subset(new_df_1, (grepl("338 4 MM",new_df_1$xprod,fixed=TRUE)==TRUE) |

                         (grepl("338 4MM",new_df_1$xprod,fixed=TRUE)==TRUE) |

                         (grepl("338 4 0 MM",new_df_1$xprod,fixed=TRUE)==TRUE) |

                         (grepl("338 4 0MM",new_df_1$xprod,fixed=TRUE)==TRUE) |

                         (grepl("338 4 00 MM",new_df_1$xprod,fixed=TRUE)==TRUE) |

                         (grepl("338 4 00MM",new_df_1$xprod,fixed=TRUE)==TRUE))
```

Please, is there a way using regular expressions or some function in R to do this automatically without inserting the several combinations of "338 4 00 MM"?

Thank you very much.

Best regards!

Comment: Please explain what you want to do, show the input and show the corresponding output desired.

Comment: does this work? `grepl("338 4[ 0]*MM",new_df_1$xprod,fixed=TRUE)` (also, no need for `==TRUE`)

Answer (score 0):

That operation might be an attempt to select an line where the xprod variable matches (exactly) one of those strings in the pattern arguments. If so you could do this economically with:

```
dose_1KG <- subset(new_df_1, xprod %in% 
                                 c("338 4 MM","338 4MM","338 4 0 MM","338 4 00 MM","338 4 00MM")
```

Using $ to pull in a variable in an expression to the second argument from the same dataframe in `subset` is just wrong. The whole point of `subset` is to permit one to avoid that necessity. If the question is how to identify rows where those expressions might be a partial match, then you might need to use `grepl` but you could still simplify with a `paste0` call that connects then with the "|" operator (and again not using "$"):

```
dose_1KG <- subset( new_df_1, 
                     grepl( paste0( c("338 4 MM","338 4MM","338 4 0 MM","338 4 00 MM","338 4 00MM"),
                            collapse="|", fixed = TRUE), # suspect the fixed argument unnecessary
                            xprod)
                   )
```

Caveat:These are untested in the absence of a MCVE,